# How do I execute a block of code whenever a reaction is added? (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to create a bot that counts how many of a certain reaction('⚪') there are to a message within a time frame. I also want to be able to skip the remaining time by reacting to a separate emoji('X'). I'm having trouble implementing the second part. Here is my code:

```
const filter = (reaction) => ['⚪'].includes(reaction.emoji.name)*/;
            MSG.awaitReactions(filter, { //MSG is the message that reactions are added to
                max: 20,
                time: 180000,
                errors: ['time'],
            })
                .then(collected => {
                    message.channel.send("Too many people.");
                })
                .catch(collected => {
                    var reaction = collected.first();
                    playerNum = reaction.count - 1;
                })
```

I was thinking I could somehow throw an error if the 'X' is reacted to, to direct the code directly to the catch statement without waiting for the time to expire. I tried putting it in the filter, but it was unsuccessful. Does anyone have a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’ll need to use a [reaction collector](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=createReactionCollector), which is what `awaitReactions` uses internally.

```js
// Same filter but include ❌
const filter = ({emoji}) => ['⚪', '❌'].includes(emoji.name);

// Create the collector
const collector = MSG.createReactionCollector(filter, {
  max: 20,
  time: 180000,
});

// collect is emitted every time someone reacts
collector.on('collect', ({emoji}) => {
  // Stop the collector on ❌
  if (emoji.name === '❌') collector.stop();
});

// end is emitted:
// when there are 20 reactions (limit)
// after 3 minutes (time) or
// when the collector is manually stopped (user by default)
collector.on('end', (collected, reason) => {
  if (reason === 'limit') message.channel.send('Too many people.');
  else {
    const reaction = collected.first();
    playerNum = reaction.count - 1;
  }
});
```